# How can I remove links in wear notification which is automatically generated by Android OS?

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I'm making Wear OS Application, and testing my app in galaxy watch devices.

One thing I hope to achieve is removing links in wear notification which is automatically generated by Android OS.

When RemoteView of Wear Notification has some kind of texts which is matched some regex rule,

Android OS (or Galaxy Watch?) seems to add link to the texts.

How can I remove links in wear notification which is automatically generated by Android OS?

[image]